# How to mock redux store that is saved to LocalStorage

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, jestjs

I am testing redux store. There is condition that if there is a store saved to localStorage then the persisted store copy should be taken.

```
let preloadedState;
const persistedState = localStorage.getItem('movieDBState');

if (persistedState) {
  preloadedState = JSON.parse(persistedState); // should code coverage this line.
}
```

My jesj code coverage report says that if condition is not taken.
I have tried to mock local storage in this way:

```
const localStorageMock = (function () {
      let localStorage = {};
      return {
        getItem(key) {
          return localStorage[key];
        },
        setItem(key, value) {
          localStorage[key] = value.toString();
        },
        clear() {
          localStorage = {};
        },
        removeItem(key) {
          delete localStorage[key];
        },
      };
    }());

    Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', { value: localStorageMock });
```

But it does not seem to work for me. Is there any way to test local storage without using any mocking library. Only with jest.

Comment: Are you simply trying to chase down code coverage for the sake of code coverage or do you have a legitimate concern that Javascript won't work on *that one line*? Have you tried mocking it directly, i.e. `window.localStorage = localStorageMock;`? What isn't working? Can you provide more details?

Comment: I just need get code coverage. I am forced to get 100 % code coverage for all files. Right now i am stuck only on this line. Here is code for my store and test: https://codepen.io/Vight/pen/dyOGxVo

Comment: Link for jest code coverage report: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ps1SXOtvZ56NyjdCmu9-YgjuRz8rRnoJ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Found workaround. Instead if statement i just put const preloadedState = JSON.parse(persistedState) || {};

So createStore does not drop if localStorage is empty and test has 100% code coverage.